# Reading data from LINQ query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, ssis, script-task

I am new to LINQ query and writing a SSIS script task to read data from two data tables.
I have created the following query, where I want to output to be sent by an email as a table. The body of the email will be the output.

I am able to see the result. But dont know how to use this data (New to linq). 
Here is my code:-

```
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Filepath As String
    Dim i As Integer


    Filename = "TM_xxx_DAILY_*" + Dts.Variables("User::VLoaddt").Value.ToString + "_*.txt"


    Filepath = Dts.Variables("User::vSrcFolder").Value.ToString

    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Filepath)
    Dim fi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles(Filename)

    Dim DestTab As DataTable
    DestTab = New DataTable("DestinationTable")

    Dim column As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Dest")
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")


    DestTab.Columns.Add(column)

    DestTab.Rows.Add("TM_xxx_ONLINE")
    DestTab.Rows.Add("TM_xxx_RETAIL")
    DestTab.Rows.Add("TM_xxx_TELESALES")
    DestTab.Rows.Add("TM_xxx_DAILY_DEVICE")

    Dim SrcTab As DataTable
    SrcTab = New DataTable("SourceTable")

    Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Source")
    column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("FileExists")
    column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    SrcTab.Columns.Add(column1)
    SrcTab.Columns.Add(column2)


    For i = 0 To fi.Length - 1
        SrcTab.Rows.Add(Left(fi.GetValue(i).ToString, Len(fi.GetValue(i).ToString) - 20), "Exists")

    Next

    Dim query =
    From a In DestTab
    Group Join b In SrcTab
        On a.Field(Of String)("dest") Equals b.Field(Of String)("Source")
        Into Group
    Let b = Group.FirstOrDefault
    Select dest = a.Field(Of String)("dest"), FileExists = If(b Is Nothing, "Missing", b.Field(Of String)("FileExists"))
```

The biggest challenge and I am not able to understand how to use the variable "query" in "Dim query". While examples in the net and able to use it as a datarow, copytodatatable and other. I can only see tostring,equals and things like that.

My objective is to read files in a folder join it with "Destinationtable" and find the missing ones.

The codes written below are the one right after the select statement

Error Screenshots
[image]
[image]

Comment: A LINQ query returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, where the type `T` depends on the specifics of your query. Generally speaking, you access the contents of an `IEnumerable` using a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. When I try to use a code like ' for each line in query console.writeline (line) next' I get error saying implicit conversion from object to inumerable, which is correct. So am I missing anything here?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the actual code that generates the error.  Also, I suggest that you copy and paste error messages.

Comment: Error screen grabs added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
For each line in query.ToList()

    Dim drRow as DataRow
    drRow = MT.NewRow
    drRow("Filename") = line.Item(0)
    MT.Rows.Add(drRow)

Next
```

Instead of

```
For each line in query
    MT.Rows.Add(query)
Next
```

Comment: One thing I would love to know is that what should be the datatype for the "line" in for each line.

Comment: In this case you can use `Object`